# How do I get the id of the last inserted record from SQLAlchemy 2 on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy 1.4 and MySQL 8.0+, I had code that returned the id of the record I just inserted into the DB. The code was this...

```
        with common.qry_engine.begin() as conn:
            result = conn.execute(common.tbl_application.insert(values=new_properties))
            self.app_id = result.inserted_primary_key[0]
```

However, after updating to SQLAlchemy 2.0+, this no longer works. What is the new way to do this? Must I run

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

to get that id?
Thanks!

Comment: I dunno, [this](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/2e0279ee5089bf6a7a5ce8b2c1377aa4) works for me.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks! Your link does seem to be what I finally came up with, too.

Answer (score 0):

After much playing and fumbling with the documentation, here is what I came up with (new_properties is a dictionary where the keys are the column names and the values are the related values I want to insert)...

```
        with common.qry_engine.begin() as conn:
            result = conn.execute(common.tbl_application.insert().values(new_properties))
            self.app_id = result.inserted_primary_key[0]
```

This seems to work well.